# Converting Watir/Watin script to Selenium Scripts

Tags: watin, watir, selenium-ide

Is it possible to automate the translation of a Watir/Waitin script to selenium? The problem is the selenium ide is only for firefox, and I need to record on Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is one reason to use a common language such as C# to write the tests as then you can port over the majority of the code and change the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Watir script, why don't you use it for both IE and FF?

```
require 'watir'

Watir::Browser.default = "ie"
#Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"

@browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

I'm not seeing where Selenium enters into that problem based on your first statement and the problem with FF/IE.